# Byte swapping using Numpy in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, byte

I'm trying to do byte-swapping using NumPy in Python.

I've created the function `swap32()` which byte swaps the bytes representation of the array that is composed of 32-bit ints. I provide a little-endian bytes object (brr) as the input in the code below and then the function swap it's bytes to convert it to big-endian. The output that my code produces is shown below (which is wrong btw).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def swap32(x):
...   y = bytearray(x)
...   a = np.array(y, dtype=np.uint32)
...   return bytes(a.byteswap())

>>> arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> brr = bytes(arr)
>>> brr
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05'

>>> swap32(brr)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05'
```

If I byteswap `brr` again then I get the following result which is incorrect because a swap32(swap32(brr)) should give back original brr.

```
>>> swap32(y)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05'
```

I'm certainly going wrong somewhere which I'm unable to figure out. Isn't there any standard way (or easy way) to swap bytes of a `bytes` object in Python?

Comment: What do you mean "a 32-bit bytes object"? Your bytes object, `bytes([1,2,3,4,5])` is not 32-bits in any sense that I can figure

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried initializing array with int32 as well. But got the same result - `\x00\x00\x00\x01`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are right that my `bytes` object is not 32 bits. What I meant to say is that I have a bytes object and I want to do byteswapping assuming that the array is made of 32bit ints.I'm updating the post. My apologies.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, I tried using np.uint8 and this removed the excess zeros but the result is still not byte swapped.

```
arr => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
swap32(bytes(arr)) => b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'

Comment: I think I understand you know, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand you now. You should use `np.frombuffer` instead of `np.array`, because `np.array` treats it's input as an *iterable*, an iterating over bytes just gives you integers. You want to treat the bytes as a raw buffer.

Note the difference:

```
>>> np.array(bytearray([1,2,3,4]), dtype=np.uint32)
array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=uint32)
>>> np.frombuffer(bytearray([1,2,3,4]), dtype=np.uint32)
array([67305985], dtype=uint32)
```

So, you want something like:

```
def swap32(x):
    return np.frombuffer(x, dtype=np.uint32).byteswap().tobytes()
```

Note, this requires that the length of your bytes object be a multiple of the item-size of the array, i.e. in this case, a multiple of 4.

Anyway, in action:

```
>>> swap32(bytes([1,2,3,4]))
b'\x04\x03\x02\x01'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm able to reproduce the results for 32 bit. Just a question, if I use this with np.uint64 (assuming the length of my bytes object is in multiples of 8) it would work, right?

Comment: @PriyanshuKhandelwal yes. And signed/unsigned shouldn't actually matter in this case, actually, but the bitlength of the type does matter.